# Javascript undefined field even though I can see it in developer tools (React & Electron)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, electron, pdf.js

I am trying to access `contentWindow.PDFViewerApplication` of a React `iframe` element as follows

```
<iframe ref={
(it)=>{
  console.log(it.contentWindow)
  console.log(it.contentWindow.PDFViewerApplication)
  }
}
src={reader+'?file='} type="application/pdf"/>
```

and I can see the PDFViewerApplication in the console, but I can't access the field. It logs `undefined`.

[image: console output in developer tools]

Does anyone know the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The react callback is called before the element has really finished loading the PDF viewer. So you have to wait (set a timeout or some other solution).